# How to add android "SDK Update Site" via command line

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using the android's sdkmanager commandline tool to update the SDK and I want to add an update site for addons. How can I do that only from commandline. I cannot use UX tool as I am accessing the host via ssh.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create this a file named `repositories.cfg` under your `~/.android/` folder.

Paste the following content into the file and modify it as needed.

```
### User Sources for Android Repository
#Tue Dec 12 15:45:09 PST 2017
disp02=Url1
disp01=Url2
disp00=Url3
count=3
enabled02=true
enabled01=true
enabled00=true
src02=http\://somewhere.com/some-extras-2/SomeArtifact2/some-extra-artifact.xml
src01=http\://somewhere.com/some-extras-1/SomeArtifact1/some-extra-artifact.xml
src00=http\://somewhere.com/some-extras-0/SomeArtifact0/some-extra-artifact.xml
```

Comment: what are those variables "disp", "count", "enabled", "src" for and where are they referenced? I mean what I need is simply add repository so it can be referenced from sdkmanager level. Also, did u find any repositores.cfg documentation?

Comment: If you are using AndroidStudio, these are directly translated to the SDK update site UI: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIgcQ.jpg

Comment: unfortunately does not seem to work with SDK only (no android studio) :(

Comment: Can you explain your issue in detail? I am not able to understand the problem you are facing.

Comment: I am trying to add some repositories to SDK manager on a remote machine (no GUI), a difference is that I have only SDK packages installed instead of Android Studio GUI + SDK's. So those flags like disp, enable, wont be referenced from Android Studio since there is no any. Anyway I have tried it, and it seems like repository link (with disp, count and enabled flags) I am placing there is ignored and never realy added to SDKmanager.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the numbering correctly? Can you paste you file here? You can just replace the URLs if there is any security concerns.

Comment: looks exacly like yours beside a fact that there is only 1 link disp00=Url3
count=1
enabled00=true
src00=http\://somewhere.com/some-extras-0/SomeArtifact0/some-extra-artifact.xml

Comment: Looks correct to me. You can try this. Create a repo using android studio with same link on local machine, then copy the repositories.cfg from path -> "~/.android" and then paste it to remote file. This can confirm your test if it is working on local, it should work on remote as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not work for password-protected repositories

Comment: Spent a lot of time trying to find a way around the credential problems @CAMOBAP mentioned, reading sources and everything. But didn't get it to work. Manual download from his answer is the only option.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like still nothing better than writing a custom script to achieve these steps:

1. Download `addon.xml`
2. Parse it to get the location of a package archive<sup>[1]</sup>
3. Download package and extract to `$ANDROID_SDK_HOME/add-ons`
4. Convert `addon.xml` to `package.xml` and place it in addon directory in Android SDK

Here is my script to do this https://gist.github.com/CAMOBAP795/b5664b05ce2130de8192516fd4c4b9b0

Prerequisites:
 - `wget`
 - `libxml2-utils`
 - `xsltproc`

<sup>[1]</sup> During development I observed that there are several XSD schemes, so my script doesn' cover all cases